# Possibility of a merger (connect) of two stores in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a question about the possibility of a merger of two stores in Magento.

Shop No. 1 and shop No. 2 store selling the same thing.
Shop No. 1 is my shop (magento).
Shop No. 2 is a system distributor/wholesale (magento).
Different SKU and ID

How to do shop No. 2 (for the distributor)?

Purchase in shop No. 1 (my store) automatically visible in shop No. 2 (magento system distributor)?
Alternatively, a solution to automatically download sales from shop No. 1

How to do?
Some settings in magento or additional plug?
I do not want "Multi store option".

Thx, for help.

Comment: Would you be willing to add another website onto the same install?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you: "do not want "Multi store option", it seems that the two stores must remain separate on two different servers? Is the underlying purpose here just to keep track of inventory, or also to push information into both stores (price changes, image changes etc?)

1) First we need to be able to associate the Products are the same "some how."

Situation Before:
Shop 1: Your Shop ie. Sku: 12345, ID: 10001
Shop 2: Wholesale Shop ie. Sku: B345, ID: 2003030

Reasonable solution would be:
 A) Create a new custom Attribute under either your store, his/her store, or both stores like: globalSku: #yourSku, 
or perhaps if you have Barcodes already, use the Barcode attribute.

Situation After:
Shop 1: Sku: 12345, ID: 10001, globalSku: g12345
Shop 2: Sku: B345, ID: 2003030, globalSku: g12345

When we're talking about visibility...
Are we talking about that the Inventory is reduced in the Wholesale's store?
Are we talking that the customer's in wholesale will now have the Order added to their history? If so, we are now dealing with adding Customers to the wholesale shop and vice versa and updating order history.

Pulling Down Product Inventory:
With the new globalSKU as a Unique ID, Pulling down product inventory status can be done via:
A) Pulled remotely via REST/SOAP Call, Pushed Automatically/Exported via Dataflow from Shop1/2.
B) Alternatively: Integration, ie: T-Hub can pull down orders and can push up order information.

Pushing Data:
A) Can be pushed remotely via REST/SOAP Call to SHOP 1/2

Additional details regarding the environment, the size of the catalog, the timeliness of the updates and if this is just inventory adjustments would be helpful for a clearer implementation.

Best,